# Can I remove boot medium after boot from live usb/cd

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, live-cd

So if I boot from usb, can I remove that usb after boot.

Also is it possible to save the session information to the boot medium or any secondary storage, so that my desktop icons etc. look the same every time I boot from usb

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not remove the USB/CD before shutting live os.

I hope this is what you're looking for.
Here is described instructions [liveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD)

> After you have finished, shut the computer down and remove the CD.
>
> At this point anything you saved to the desktop or Documents folders and such will vanish - only things you saved into folders on the hard-drive will remain. This means that there won't be any trace of your personal data (e-mails, passwords etc.) left on the machine, which can be quite useful if you don't trust the Windows installation on the computer.